# ffmpeg square resizing doesn't resize correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to resize a video to a square 1:1 640x640 format.

`ffmpeg -i /Users/yagiz/Desktop/video-creator/whats-unfinished.mp4 -y -vcodec libx264 -filter:v scale=w='if(gt(a,1),640,trunc(640*a/2)*2)':h='if(lt(a,1),640,trunc(640/a/2)*2)',pad=w=640:h=640:x='if(gt(a,1),0,(640-iw)/2)':y='if(lt(a,1),0,(640-ih)/2)':color=black /Users/yagiz/Desktop/video-creator/whats.mp4`

The processed video has a resolution of 1152 × 480

But the output is: 638 × 640

Do you know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the SAR to 1 after padding.

`ffmpeg -i /Users/yagiz/Desktop/video-creator/whats-unfinished.mp4 -y -vcodec libx264 -filter:v scale=w='if(gt(dar,1),640,trunc(640*dar/2)*2)':h='if(gt(dar,1),trunc(640/dar/2)*2,640)',pad=w=640:h=640:x='(ow-iw)/2':y='(oh-ih)/2':color=black,setsar=1 /Users/yagiz/Desktop/video-creator/whats.mp4`

Comment: I've tried the following command @Gyan still didn't work: 

ffmpeg -i /Users/yagiz/Desktop/video-creator/whats-unfinished.mp4 -y -vcodec libx264 -filter:v setsar=1,scale=w='if(gt(a,1),640,trunc(640*a/2)*2)':h='if(lt(a,1),640,trunc(640/a/2)*2)',pad=w=640:h=640:x='if(gt(a,1),0,(640-iw)/2)':y='if(lt(a,1),0,(640-ih)/2)':color=black /Users/yagiz/Desktop/video-creator/whats.mp4